# Bandpass filtering in Python

Tags: python, fft, gaussian

I have a noisy signal `a` on which I've performed a Fourier transform (`A = fft(a)`). The original signal has a frequency of 2 Hz.

I'm supposed to remove the noise by multiplying by a Gaussian function,

`gaussian = exp(-(abs(v) - 2)**2)/(2*(0.5**2))`

where `v` is a frequency in Hz. What am I supposed to use for `v`? A single number? Some span of values?

Comment: See scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d